# WSE 2.0 SP2 on WindowsServer 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012, wse

I moved an old application to `WS2012R2`. Now it throws :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Services2, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies
```

Is it possible somehow install `WSE 2.0 SP2` to `WS2012R2` ?

As much as I have googled, I can't find any solution which doesn't include upgrading assembly itself to a newer one.

Comment: Used nuGet to get the libary. In Reference set Copy Local = true, from web.config removed old assambly. Not the solution i asked for but worked. (Found source of that old app, other way wouldnt be able to do that)